# QProcess problems, output of process

Tags: qt, qt4

I am trying to figure out the use of QProcess.  I looked at Qt doc with no luck.
http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qprocess.html

**EXAMPLES OF PROBLEM.**

**Example 1:** Code bellow works.

```
    #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QProcess>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);    

    QProcess cmd;
    
    cmd.start("cmd");
    if (!cmd.waitForStarted())  {
        return false;
    }

    cmd.waitForReadyRead();
    QByteArray result = cmd.readAll();
    //qout << result.data() << endl;   //console junk captured, doesn't show. 

    //My test command
    cmd.write("echo hello");
    cmd.write("\n");

    //Capture my result
    cmd.waitForReadyRead();
    //This is my command shown by cmd, I don't show it, capture & discard it.
    result = cmd.readLine();
    //Read result of my command ("hello") and the rest of output like cur dir.   
    result = cmd.readAll();    
    qout << result.data();

    qout << "\n\n---End, bye----" << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

The **output** of the above code is

> hello
>
> ```
> F:\Dev_Qt\expControllingExtConsoleApps-build-desktop>
>
> ---End, bye----
> ```

The problem is that if I try to use ipconfig or 7zip in this fashion via Qprocess and cmd console, I am unable to see any output from ipconfig or 7zip.  I don't know if anything is even done, if something is done then why can't I see the output?  Code below illustrates.

**Example 2:**  Does not work.  Can't use ipconfig.

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QTextStream qout(stdout);
   
   QProcess cmd2;
    cmd2.setWorkingDirectory("C:/Program Files/7-Zip");   //not needed in this example.
    cmd2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    cmd2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

    cmd2.start("cmd");
    if (!cmd2.waitForStarted())
    {
        qout << "Error: Could not start!" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    cmd2.waitForReadyRead();
    QByteArray result = cmd2.readAll();
    qout << result.data() << endl;      //Console version info, etc.

    //My command
    cmd2.write("ipconfig");
    cmd2.write("\n");

    //Capture output of ipconfig command
    //DOES NOT WORK!!
    cmd2.waitForReadyRead();
    while (! cmd2.atEnd())
    {
        result = cmd2.readLine();
        qout << result;
        result.clear();
    }
    qout << endl;

    qout << "\n\n---end----" << endl;
    return a.exec();

}
```

**Output** is below, it is missing the ipconfig connection information result. No output from ipconfig is captured at all.

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version
> 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Program Files\7-Zip> ipconfig
>
> ---end----

Should have been more like this (with ipconfig result).

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version
> 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Documents and
> Settings\noname>ipconfig
>
> Windows IP Configuration
>
> Ethernet adapter Local Area
> Connection:
>
> ```
>     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
>     IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.172.148.135
>     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
>     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.172.148.177
> ```
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\noname>

Obviously the output should should have been a little diff than above but the Connection info which is the output of "ipconfig" should have been captured.  In the same way if I try to use 7zip via cmd console... I can not see/capture any output of 7zip.  So my question is how can I use command line apps like ipconfig and 7zip via QProcess and cmd console and see the result of the output of these applications?

**Example 3:**  7zip does not work

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QProcess>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   QTextStream qout(stdout);

    QProcess cmd2;
    cmd2.setWorkingDirectory("C:/Program Files/7-Zip");
    cmd2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    cmd2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);

    cmd2.start("cmd");
    if (!cmd2.waitForStarted()) {
        return false;
    }

    //My Command
    cmd2.write("7z.exe");
    cmd2.write("\n");

    //Capture output of ipconfig command
    cmd2.waitForReadyRead();
    QByteArray result;

    while (! cmd2.atEnd()) {
        result = cmd2.readLine();
        qout << result;
        result.clear();
    }
    qout << endl;

    qout << "\n\n---end----" << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

**Output** below. Does not show anything from 7zip.

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version
> 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe
>
> ---end----

Output is expected to be along the lines of...

> Microsoft Windows XP [Version
> 5.1.2600] (C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\noname>cd
> C:\Program Files\7-Zip
>
> C:\Program Files\7-Zip>7z.exe
>
> 7-Zip 9.15 beta  Copyright (c)
> 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-06-20
>
> Usage: 7z  [...]
> <archive_name> [<file_names>...]
> [<@listfiles...>]
>
> a: Add files to archive
> b: Benchmark   d: Delete files from
> archive   e: Extract files from
> archive (without using directory
> names)   l: List contents of archive
> t: Test integrity of archive   u:
> Update files to archive   x: eXtract
> files with full paths 
> -ai[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include archives
> -ax[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude archives   -bd: Disable
> percentage indicator
> -i[r[-|0]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: Include filenames   -m{Parameters}:
> set compression Method
> -o{Directory}: set Output directory   -p{Password}: set Password   -r[-|0]: Recurse subdirectories   -scs{UTF-8 |
> WIN | DOS}: set charset for list files
> -sfx[{name}]: Create SFX archive   -si[{name}]: read data from stdin   -slt: show technical information for l (List) command   -so: write data to
> stdout   -ssc[-]: set sensitive case
> mode   -ssw: compress shared files
> -t{Type}: Set type of archive   -u[-][p#][q#][r#][x#][y#][z#][!newArchiveName]:
> Update options   -v{Size}[b|k|m|g]:
> Create volumes   -w[{path}]: assign
> Work directory. Empty path means a
> temporary directory
> -x[r[-|0]]]{@listfile|!wildcard}: eXclude filenames   -y: assume Yes on
> all queries
>
> C:\Program Files\7-Zip>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

eI see one big problem.
Under windows you issue a commend pressing the Enter key. Writing

```
cmd.write("command");
cmd.write("\n");
```

just isn't enough you have to write

```
cmd.write("command");
cmd.write("\n\r");
```

Notice the trailing \r. Try this, it should work better, and by better I mean 7zip. I don't know if you'll get ipconfig to work properly.

Good luck and best regards
D

EDIT
Here is a working solution:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QtCore/QProcess>
#include <QtCore/QString>
#include <QtCore/QTextStream>

// Not clean, but fast
QProcess *g_process = NULL;

// Needed as a signal catcher
class ProcOut : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
  ProcOut (QObject *parent = NULL);
  virtual ~ProcOut() {};

public slots:
  void readyRead();
  void finished();
};

ProcOut::ProcOut (QObject *parent /* = NULL */):
QObject(parent)
{}

void
ProcOut::readyRead()
{
  if (!g_process)
    return;

  QTextStream out(stdout);
  out << g_process->readAllStandardOutput() << endl;
}

void
ProcOut::finished()
{
  QCoreApplication::exit (0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QCoreApplication *app = new QCoreApplication (argc, argv);

  ProcOut *procOut = new ProcOut();
  g_process        = new QProcess();

  QObject::connect (g_process, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()),
    procOut, SLOT(readyRead()));
  QObject::connect (g_process, SIGNAL(finished (int, QProcess::ExitStatus)),
    procOut, SLOT(finished()));

  g_process->start (QLatin1String ("cmd"));
  g_process->waitForStarted();

  g_process->write ("ipconfig\n\r");

  // Or cmd won't quit
  g_process->write ("exit\n\r");

  int result = app->exec();

  // Allright, process finished.
  delete procOut;
  procOut = NULL;

  delete g_process;
  g_process = NULL;

  delete app;
  app = NULL;

  // Lets us see the results
  system ("pause");

  return result;
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Hope that helps. It worked everytime on my machine.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem to make a diff.  I have come to realize one thing though --> with AND without \r... it does sometimes work.  If i run the application 10 times, maybe 50% of the time it works and 50% of the time it does not.  Replication tip: wait diff amount of time between re-running application.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly why, but I tried it differently. Without the use of `waitForReadyRead()` but instead I connected to the `readyReadStandardOutput()` signal of the `QProcess` and used the `readStandardOutput()` method of the `QProcess`. It worked like a cham. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 4):

Even though Dariusz Scharsig already provided a solution to the problem, I would like to point out what I believe to be the actual problem(s) which can be solved using the signal slot mechanism.

**Problem 1.** The condition in your while loop is based on `bool QProcess::atEnd () const` which is according to [QProcess Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#atEnd) states:

> Reimplemented from QIODevice::atEnd().
>
> Returns true if the process is
>   not running, and no more data is available for reading; otherwise
>   returns false.

But if you looking the documentation for [QIODevice::atEnd()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qiodevice.html#atEnd), it states:

> Returns true if the current read and write position is at the end of
>   the device (i.e. there is no more data available for reading on the
>   device); otherwise returns false.
>
> **For some devices, atEnd() can return
>   true even though there is more data to read.** This special case only
>   applies to devices that generate data in direct response to you
>   calling read() (e.g., /dev or /proc files on Unix and Mac OS X, or
>   **console input / stdin on all platforms**).

**Solution 1.** Change the while loop condition to check the state of your process: `while(cmd2.state()!=QProcess::NotRunning){`.

**Problem 2.** You use `cmd2.waitForReadyRead();` outside of the loop. Perhaps some data is ready for reading now and when you finished reading, some more gets made available:

- you read the commands you just wrote : `ipconfig\n`
- ipconfig takes some time to start up and send text to the console. But by then you have already exited your loop because `atEnd()` gave true even though your process is still running.

**Solution 2.** place the `waitForReadyRead()` inside your loop.

**Consequence 2.** `waitForReadyRead()` will tell you when there is data available, which could be more than one Line, so you should consequently also change the `cmd2.ReadLine()` to `cmd2.ReadAll()`.

**Problem 3.** As documented in [QProcess::closeWriteChannel()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qprocess.html#closeWriteChannel)

> Closing the write channel is necessary for programs that read input
>   data until the channel has been closed.

**Solution 3.** One of the following options should work when finished writing your inputs

- End the process: `cmd2.write("exit\n");`
- close the Writechannel: `cmd2.closeWriteChannel();`

Working code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>    

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);
    QByteArray result;
    QProcess cmd2;

    cmd2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    cmd2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    cmd2.start("cmd");
    if (!cmd2.waitForStarted()){
        qout << "Error: Could not start!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cmd2.write("ipconfig\n");
    cmd2.closeWriteChannel();   //done Writing

    while(cmd2.state()!=QProcess::NotRunning){
        cmd2.waitForReadyRead();
        result = cmd2.readAll();
        qout << result;
    }
    qout << endl << "---end----" << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

I wrote this answer just to explain the way I understand your problem and found a solution but would like to emphasize that the **Preferable Solution** is to use the [Signal/Slot Mechanism as presented by Dariusz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5893756/2078851).

Comment: hi, I tried the same code in linux. Only changed "cmd" to "xterm" and "ipconfig" to "ifconfig" but its not working. Could you please help me?

Comment: @ishan3243 Hi, I was using Qt in a windows environment. I now setup Qt on a linux distro, tried it and got the same result. So I investigated a bit as I was curious as well. According to [this Qt bug report](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36109) xterm doesn't read stdin or send anything to stdout. So monitoring these channels it would be normal that you have nothing to read. As [this forum thread](http://compgroups.net/comp.unix.programmer/pipe-to-process-running-in-xterm/177837) suggests, using a named pipe with xterm and reading and writing there could work.