# Getting linux terminal value from my application

Tags: linux, qt, qt4

I am developing a Qt application in Linux. I wanted to pass Linux commands to a terminal. That worked but now i also want to get a response from the terminal for this specific command.

For example,

```
ls -a
```

As you know this command lists the directories and files of the current working directory. I now want to pass the returned values from the ls call to my application. What is a correct way to do this?

Comment: You can find the working examples to `QProcess` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5893756/167814).

Answer (score 3):

[QProcess](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html) is the qt class that will let you spawn a process and read the result. There's an example of usage for reading the result of a command on that page.

Comment: I'd add that the relevant section is "Communicating via Channels"

Comment: I've tried but i can not get it done.
QString program = "ls -a";
    QStringList arguments;
    arguments << "-a";


    myProcess->start(program, arguments);

    QByteArray result  = myProcess->readAllStandardOutput ();

Comment: Your program name is wrong; `ls -a` does not exist on any Linux system I've ever seen. The program is `ls`, the `-a` is an argument.

Comment: i know which one is argument or which one is command =)
i solved my problem with adding the "waitForFinished();" before the "myProcess->readAllStandardOutput ();"

Answer (score 0):

popen() ，  api of linux systerm , return FILE * that you can read it like a file descriptor， may help youp erhaps。

Comment: qt may have the same function api just like popen()

Answer (score 0):

Parsing `ls(1)` output is dangerous -- make a few files with funny names in a directory and test it out:

```
touch "one file"
touch "`printf "\x0a\x0a\x0ahello\x0a  world"`"
```

That creates *two* files in the current working directory. I expect your attempts to parse `ls(1)` output won't work. This might be alright if you're showing the results to a *human*, (though a human will be immensely confused if a filename includes output that looks just like `ls(1)` output!) but if you're trying to present something like an `explorer.exe` or `Finder.app` representation of files in the filesystem, this is *horribly broken*.

Instead, use `opendir(3)`, `readdir(3)`, and `closedir(3)` to read directory entries yourself. This will be safer, more portable, and (as a side benefit) slightly better performing.