# Writing to the terminal using Qt

Tags: linux, qt, qprocess

I needed to execute terminal commands by giving input to the terminal through Qt. Also I want to read the output. I found one solution that works on windows ([QProcess problems, output of process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890955/qprocess-problems-output-of-process)). Here is the code:

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QString>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextStream qout(stdout);
    QByteArray result;
    QProcess cmd2;

    cmd2.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
    cmd2.setProcessChannelMode(QProcess::MergedChannels);
    cmd2.start("cmd");
    if (!cmd2.waitForStarted()){
        qout << "Error: Could not start!" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
    cmd2.write("ipconfig\n");
    cmd2.closeWriteChannel();   //done Writing

    while(cmd2.state()!=QProcess::NotRunning){
        cmd2.waitForReadyRead();
        result = cmd2.readAll();
        qout << result;
    }
    qout << endl << "---end----" << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

In ubuntu, I change "cmd" to "xterm" and "ipconfig" to "ifconfig" but its not working!

Comment: `its not working` is not working. Please explain what the actual output is. Also, why are you not getting the network data with proper Qt classes?

Comment: there is no output. When I close the xterm window, it just prints "---end----" in the console application.

Comment: the purpose is not to get network data. I am trying to execute shell commands by writing to stdin of the terminal using Qt. ifconfig is just an example

Comment: So you question can be demonstrated by using the `passwd` binary on Linux and you would like to feed it with the actual password, for instance? Is that it?

Comment: no no no....i want to open the terminal. And I want to feed the whole command (including the binary and the arguments). For eg I could do p.write(

)

Comment: Why do you want to open the terminal?

Comment: no. I want to feed the whole thing (the binary and the arguments). For eg I could do p.write("ls\n") where p is an instance of QProcess.

Comment: I want to open the terminal because my app requires it. Sorry I can't go in depth of my app right now

Comment: Well, you need to explain the use case to get the best advice. It is possible that opening the terminal is red-herring, but it may be valid. This needs clarification. It is not clear at this point what you are trying to achieve, at least to me.

Comment: I am replicating an app that's developed in C# in windows. It does open the cmd. I am writing the same app in Qt to make it cross platform. So I need to open the terminal.

Comment: I am not particularly interested in the C# application. I am more interested in what the use case is. Potentially, it might be that porting is better with dropping this concept. Do not tell us what it was doing, but tell us what it tries to achieve. You need to understand what it tries to achieve in order to port it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out a solution. Use bash instead of xterm. I am really not sure why this works. My guess is that when I was using xterm, it was opening a separate window, and the xterm process was detached from thr main process. But in bash, its doing everything in the same terminal as the qt console app.

Comment: xterm doesn't take its input on the standard input, it gets the input as X11 events. I really don't see why you're running a shell at all. You can run `ipconfig` directly, without having to run a shell of any kind